# How is a4j:form submitted when a4j:commandButton has no "action" attribute

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jsf-1.2

Currently I'm learning RichFaces and read through some demo on site,http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/commandButton.jsf?c=commandButton&tab=usage

```html
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
  xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">

<style>
    .gridhello {
        border-collapse : collapse;
    }
    .gridhellocolumn {
        padding-left : 0;
    }
    .outhello {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>

<a4j:form>
    <h:panelGrid columns="3" styleClass="gridhello" columnClasses="gridhellocolumn">
        <h:outputText value="Name:" />
        <h:inputText value="#{userBean.name}" />
        **<a4j:commandButton value="Say Hello" reRender="out" />**
    </h:panelGrid>
</a4j:form>
<rich:spacer height="7"/>
<br />
<h:panelGroup id="out">
    <h:outputText value="Hello " rendered="#{not empty userBean.name}" styleClass="outhello" />
    <h:outputText value="#{userBean.name}" styleClass="outhello" />
    <h:outputText value="!" rendered="#{not empty userBean.name}" styleClass="outhello" />
</h:panelGroup>

<br />
```

code line  has no "action" attribute, I'm just wondering how it still works, what's the default method of back bean was called in this case so that userBean.name was updated?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

When you do a submit, the form data is sent into the mapped attributes of the managed bean. That's default behavior for `UICommand`s: `<h:commandButton>`, `<h:commandLink>`, `<a4j:commandButton>`, `<a4j:commandLink>` and others like `<a4j:jsFunction>`. Even if you don't declare an action to execute, the form data is submitted to the server through a POST request and the JSF lifecycle will fire. As part of the lifecycle, in the Update Model phase, JSF will set the data bound from the components into the managed bean attributes, then the Invoke Applications phase will perform any action (if available) and in the end the Render Response phase will generate the response and update the View (JSP, Facelets). In this case, since it's an ajax call, the view will be updated; more exactly, the component with id `"out"` will be updated. Note that this `"out"` content is outside the `<a4j:form>`, the values here won't be sent to server, still the `reRender` will update their values with the view model values.

UPDATE:

The line `<h:inputText value="#{userBean.name}"` is binding the `name` attribute of the `UserBean` managed bean with the value of the `<h:inputText>` component. This is a basic concept from JSF. Remember that RichFaces is not a JSF implementation, it extends the framework and add functionalities like ajax support for RIA.

This line

```html
<h:outputText value="#{userBean.name}" styleClass="outhello" />
```

means: bind the value of `name` attribute of the `UserBean` managed bean to the outputText component. Still, this is outside the form, so the actual value of this component won't be sent on the server.

Some resorces to learn more about JSF:

- [StackOverflow JSF wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info)
- [Developing an Application with JSF 1.2](http://jsflessons.blogspot.com/)
- [JSF Tutorials](http://jsftutorials.net/)
- [The BalusC Code](http://balusc.blogspot.com/). BalusC is a JSF expert and you can find lot of info about JSF and best practices with JSF.
- [JSF lifecycle](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rsahelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.jsf.doc/topics/cjsf.html)
- [JSF 2 lifecycle](http://www.java-tutorial.ch/java-server-faces/jsf-2-lifecycle)
- [Why JSF calls getters multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times/2090062#2090062)

Comment: Hi Luiggi, thanks for your detailed explanations!

After your comments, however, there is still one thing I'm not so clear about here. _<h:inputText value="#{userBean.name}" />_ has no name attribute and is not bound to any field of back bean. How could RichFaces/JSF figure out such as connection between this inputText and a certain field of back bean when this form is submitted? It'll be great if you point to me some documentations on this issue. And I can read it further by myself.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @user1540244 answer edited. An advice: before you start learning RichFaces (or another JSF based framework like PrimeFaces or OmniFaces) I recommend you to have a good understanding of plain JSF.